# Why is "set -x" (xtrace) output not subject to redirections unless wrapped in braces?

Tags: bash

I am enabling echoing of commands in a bash script using "set -x".  When I turn off echoing, I am issuing "set +x" but I don't want that command echo'd.  To do this, I issue the command:

```
{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null
```

This works fine.  However, I'm not completely understanding why this works and the following does not:

```
set +x 2>/dev/null
```

Obviously the echoing of the command doesn't go to stderr, but I'm not really understanding why the command with the semicolon in the curly braces works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason you need to use braces is that `xtrace` logging (the `+ set +x` line you're trying to suppress) is not output *from* the command `set +x` itself (a command which, on its own, writes nothing to either stderr *or* stdout). Instead, it's output from *the shell invoking* `set +x`.

When you run `set +x 2>/dev/null`, that redirects stderr to `/dev/null` *only for the execution of `set +x` itself*. It **does not** redirect things the shell does while setting up to run that command, which includes printing trace logs.

By contrast, when you run `{ set +x; } 2>/dev/null`, that does the redirection *before running the entire block of code*, which includes by nature pre-command setup for each command within that block. Thus, the setup for the command is run in the redirected environment as well.

*You wouldn't want it to be otherwise -- what use would `set -x` be if `someprogram 2>/dev/null` didn't log that it had invoked `someprogram` at all?*

---

Incidentally, this is very similar to why the shell-builtin `time` command's output is not subject to redirection unless wrapped in a larger context; for more on that, see [BashFAQ #32](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/032).